# block on fd which is used as exclusive lock

Tags: c, unix

A process (process-1) creates a fd as follows:

```
fd = open(FILE_PATH, O_CREAT, 0644);
```

There are multiple processes trying to communicate with process-1.

And they do it by first aquiring exclusive lock on fd created by process-1.

```
flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
```

If they acquire lock, they can communicate with process-1.

Is there anyway in which I can put process-1 in sleep and it gets awaken only when other processes try flock and succeed.

Basically I want process-1 to block (sleep) on fd that it created.

From my requirements, I tried to put this in a simple way.

**Edit:**
Following has more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715569/block-on-general-file-descriptor

Comment: maybe you want epoll?

Comment: Thanks, but Im not sure whether epoll does anything on general/normal file descriptor. fd that I described above is not a socket fd. I will try this.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Chances are there are other ways to accomplish your goal rather than trying to force this to work.

Comment: @Duck Please refer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715569/block-on-general-file-descriptor

Comment: You can do that with a condition variable or two semaphores.  Why are you trying to force this scheme to work?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by condition variable (in this context)?

Comment: Consider the semaphores first.  Server creates 2 sems along with shared memory.  Clients open semaphores and shared mem.  Clients wait until they acquire sem1 and can write.  Clients signal (post) sem2 so server does its thing.  Server posts to sem1 so next client can proceed and goes back to waiting on sem2.  Server just blocks on the sem2 thereby eliminating your whole endless spinning loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using synchronization on a file for interprocess communication  is quite uncommon.

Normally unix domain sockets, pipes or tcp / udp sockets are used for interprocess communication. The server (your process-1) sets up a listening socket and waits for other processes to connect or waits for them to send data if a connection already exists. For this it can use poll or select or in case of a threaded server it can also just use a blocking read / recv to wait for data from other processes. Locks are not required for synchronization since each process has its own connection to the server process.

See the socket manpage for a starting point.